# dropdown disappears as mouse leave the hover link

Tags: html, css

I am designing a site where I in top menu I have dropdown the dropdown appears when I hover over the link but as I leave the link the dropdown disappears i don't want to do it in jquery i only want to do it in css please help me out .
Here is the html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title>Cusit</title>
</head>
    <body>
     <!-- starting of Navbar menu -->
    <nav id="navigation">
     <!-- starting of social navigation icons -->
        <div id="social_navigation">
           <a href="www.facebook.com"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="facbook"></a>
           <a href="www.facebook.com"><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="facbook"></a>
           <a href="www.facebook.com"><img src="images/linkedin.png" alt="facbook"></a>
        </div>
        <!-- end of social navigation icons -->
        <div id="menu">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Contact us</a>

        <a href="#" id="submenu">Cusit</a>
         <ul id="drop">
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 1">Sub Nav Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 2">Sub Nav Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 3">Sub Nav Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 4">Sub Nav Link 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 5">Sub Nav Link 5</a></li>
         </ul>      
        <a href="#">Welcome</a>
        <a href="#">cutec</a>
        </div>



         <div id="searchform">
         <input type="text" class="inp">
         </div>

         <div id="searchformlogo">
         <img src="images/search.png">
         </div>
    </nav>
     <!-- End of Navbar menu -->
```

Here is the css.

```
/* starting of navigation bar */
#navigation {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: #000;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
    /* Adds shadow to the bottom of the bar */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #000000;
    /* Adds the transparent background */
    background-color:#f0eeef;
    color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);
}

#navigation a {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;   
     -webkit-transition: all .50s ease;
     -moz-transition: all .50s ease;
     -ms-transition: all .50s ease;
     -o-transition: all .50s ease;
     transition: all .50s ease;
}

#navigation a:hover {
    color: red;
} 

/* start of sub menu */
#navigation>#menu>a:nth-child(3):hover +#drop{display:block; -webkit-transition: all .50s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .50s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .50s ease;
    -o-transition: all .50s ease;
    transition: all .50s ease;
}
#drop{ display:none; width:10%; position:absolute; left:0; background:#FFFFFF; margin-left: 48em; list-style:none; margin-top:-3px;}
/* End of sub menu */
```

[here is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/so1oxjk4/)

Comment: So the dropdown disappears.... and it shouldn't? What is your expected behavior is unclear.

Comment: i want when user hover over Cusit link the dropdown must appear but and it do appears but when i leave the cusit link the dropdown disappear immediately i want that it should stop after moving from the parent link to child links but it disappear and i get really tired but i couldn't configure it please help me out

Comment: Of course it disappears, because it appears on a completely different screen position that is not “connected” to the menu point at all – so there is no way to move them mouse from the menu point to the sub-menu without leaving the menu point.

Answer (score 0):

This code works, I have used it many times it was written by  Tirumal at http://code-tricks.com/simple-css-drop-down-menu/.

you can just alter the CSS and HTML to fit your requirements, Let me know if you need a hand to alter the code.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 5</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS3**

```
    /*Initialize*/
ul#menu, ul#menu ul.sub-menu {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}
ul#menu li, ul#menu ul.sub-menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
/*Link Appearance*/
ul#menu li a, ul#menu li ul.sub-menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #666;
    padding: 5px;
    display:inline-block;
}
/*Make the parent of sub-menu relative*/
ul#menu li {
    position: relative;
}
/*sub menu*/
ul#menu li ul.sub-menu {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
ul#menu li:hover ul.sub-menu {
    display:block;
}
```